# Audi 2.0T Tapping Noise When Accelerating (Up to 3000 RPM only)

Tags: engine, vw, maintenance, audi

Car: 2013 Audi A4 2.0 4-Cyl Turbocharged AWD
Mileage: 71,457 miles
Video Clip:  https://youtu.be/HX1wXk84wq8

The car is exhibiting a tapping noise when the engine is under load at lower RPMs.
Test drove the car for about an hour and here are some of the things that I have observed...

Sound comes ON: * When accelerating from a stop or a roll in tiptronic(manual) or "D/S" mode where the RPM is allowed to rise to about 3000 RPM
* Medium to heavy acceleration from a stop or roll up to 3000 RPM
* Most of the time (8/10) with the above conditions

Sound OFF: * When idling
* When revving in "P" or "N"
* When cruising
* When accelerating in "D/S" with a light foot where the car shifts at around 2000 RPM

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, that tick could be due to an exhaust leak.  See [here](https://forums.tdiclub.com/index.php?threads/ticking-under-hard-acceleration.478596/) for other users' experiences.  Fortunately, you can check for exhaust leaks very easily and repair them yourself for under $50 if you are at all handy.  I am actually in the process of doing so myself using [this instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-exs1iMLFU).